# Is it possible to use the ServiceStack templates in Visual Studio 2017 or 2019?

Tags: servicestack, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to use the ServiceStack templates in Visual Studio 2017 or 2019? I've seen the documentation reference VS Code. I'm able to run the projects in VS 2019. If there is a place ask ServiceStack, I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

All [ServiceStack Project Templates](https://docs.servicestack.net/web-new) should work in Visual Studio, eventually all .NET Core projects will be upgraded to use .NET Core 3.1 LTS when it's released where you'll need to use VS 2019.

But most of the [Single Page App Templates](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-single-page-apps) utilizes npm utils to provide web transformations and each SPA Framework has unique formats like Vue's SFC's, React JSX and .svelte templates which are poorly supported in Visual Studio, you'll have a much better development experience using either [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) with first-class support for these formats and much better Terminal integration to run watched npm utils.

If I needed to use Visual Studio I'd only use it for all back-end C# development whilst using VS Code for all front-end development and running built-in npm utils in its multi terminal window support.

Otherwise for non SPA project templates using Visual Studio should provide a good development experience.

> If there is a place ask ServiceStack, I haven't found it yet.

If you're asking if there's a specific place to ask ServiceStack questions, you can use the [ServiceStack Customer Forums](https://forums.servicestack.net/).

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you.